# How To Add A SubViewController In The Middle Of The MainViewController

Tags: uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I want to add a subviewcontroller in the main viewcontroller, but I just want that covers one section, not all the screen. I want it in the middle of the screen. And also, want to know if I can make this subviewcontroller transparent, so I still can see the image background of my main viewcontroller.
Currently, I have my mainviewcontroller and I add another viewcontroller using this way:

```
MenuAllEntriesViewController *menuAE = [[MenuAllEntriesViewController alloc] init];
[menuAE setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
[self presentModalViewController:menuAE animated:YES];
```

But my subviewcontroller covers all the screen...
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To do this programmatically:
First add an empty `UIView` to your main view. Also create an IBOutlet from your `MainWindowController` to the view. This will be the container view of your child view controller. Just set its size and position to where you want to display child view.

Then in your `MainWindowController.m` you can use the following code to add a child view controller whose view is being displayed in the specified view within your main view:

```
//keep a strong reference to the view controller
self.otherViewController = [[OtherViewController alloc] init]; 
[self addChildViewController:otherViewController];
//set the frame
CGFloat width = containerView.frame.size.width;
CGFloat height = containerView.frame.size.height;
self.otherViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
[containerView addSubview:self.otherViewController.view];
[self.otherViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

---

If you use Storyboards and target iOS 6, you don't even need to do any programming. In the Storyboard view (formerly called Interface Builder) you can just drop a `Container View` from the Objects Library to your main view. Interface Builder will automatically create a child view controller but you can also point the containment segue to any other view controller.

Comment: I think that last line should be `[self.otherViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];`